# ZF Db Append to column

Tags: database, zend-framework, zend-db

Im trying to make an update similar to this with Zend_Db:

```
UPDATE `TABLE` SET
  column = column + 'new value'
WHERE
  foo = 'bar'
```

any of you have done this before? is it possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of [Zend_Db_Expr](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.columns-expr) this is possible.

Example:

```
$newValue = 101;
$data     = array('column' =>
                  new Zend_Db_Expr($db->quoteInto('column + ?', $newValue)));
$where    = $db->quoteInto('foo = ?', 'bar');

$updated = $db->update('TABLE', $data, $where);
```

Resulting Query:

```
UPDATE `TABLE` SET `column` = `column` + 101 WHERE `foo` = 'bar';
```

If you are asking how to append a string, then the code is similar, but you cannot use the `+` operator when dealing with character data, instead use [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat).

For example, change the `$data` array to this:

```
$data  = array('varcharCol' =>
               new Zend_Db_Expr(
                   $db->quoteInto('CONCAT(varcharCol, ?)', ' append more text!')
         ));
```

Comment: Excelent, that's exactly what I was specting. I knew it has something to do with `Zend_Db_Expr()` but didn't knew how to implement it